# Recursive bash loop array null

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have a function to which I am passing a path.
What happens is `function setSub` calls `function testSub` and under certain conditions `testSub` calls `setSub` with a different path.

Here is what I have so far

```
shopt -s nullglob 
function setSub() {
    local assets=("$1"/*)   
    echo ${#assets[@]} ######### Here
    for asset in "${assets[@]}";
    do
        if [ -d "$asset" ]; then
            setSub "$asset"
        fi;
    done
}
```

The place I marked 'Here' outputs the array length. Problem is whenever it calls itself the `assets` array is 0. The above sample should drill down and list the number of items in a directory. (What the sample does, not what my whole script does)

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you could get the output you're looking for with a simple `find "$1"` or similar. Also the `assets` array will be empty whenever it's iterating over a file rather than a directory.

Comment: It is ok in my testing (obviosly, adding a final "setSub $1" to the script) and executing it as "myscript ."

Answer (score 0):

It seems what I was looking for was `shopt -s dotglob`
My test case only had dot files in the directory.

But after @l0b0 suggestion I did a bit of research and found [this](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html).
After reading about the issues with globing, I thought it best to replace it with `find`